# Difference between SendKeys() and Keydown() in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, action, keydown, sendkeys

I am using Actions class to do the C# selenium automation testing for FireFox Driver.

I am testing the Auto-Save textarea (click the textarea to make the content editable, and change anything to click anywhere outside / click tab to auto-save the text content).

Initially I use the following Code 1, it only do the "Control+a" action but it does not do the rest:

```
actions = new Actions(this._driver);
actions.MoveToElement(element);
actions.SendKeys(Keys.Control + 'a').Build().Perform();
actions.SendKeys(Keys.Backspace).Build().Perform();
actions.SendKeys("new input").SendKeys(Keys.Tab).Build().Perform();
```

Then I changed it to the following code 2, it works.

```
actions = new Actions(this._driver);
actions.MoveToElement(element);
actions.KeyDown(Keys.Control).SendKeys("a").KeyUp(Keys.Control).Build().Perform();
actions.SendKeys(Keys.Backspace).Build().Perform();
actions.SendKeys("new input").SendKeys(Keys.Tab).Build().Perform();
```

It looks the 2 codes are same, but they have different behaviours, really appreciated if anyone can help to point out why they have different behaviours?

Comment: I think the `SendKeys` method works for keys other than Ctrl, Alt, Shift, and hence for Ctrl you would need to use  `KeyDown`

Comment: @vmachan maybe that is the reason, but when I try only actions.SendKeys(Keys.Control + 'a').Build().Perform(); the driver is able to select all text, behaving like Control + A, which I believe the SendKeys is able to work for Keys.Control.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Actions.Sendkeys methods,then modifier keys (like ctrl,shift etc) are not released..That's why in the first code,

```
actions.SendKeys(Keys.Control + 'a').Build().Perform(); /// send ctrl keys & holds it

actions.SendKeys(Keys.Backspace).Build().Perform(); //performs control+backspace which does nothing
```